# Runtime enum description in scala

Tags: scala, enums

I'm looking for enum in Scala that provides the description of one of its option dependent on runtime.

For example, an Answer enum, that allows user to anser yes/no and also other whilst specifying some message.

```
object Answer extends Enumeration {
    type Answer = Value

    val Yes = Value("yes")
    val No = Value("no")
    val Other = ???

    def apply(id: Int, msg: String = null) = {
        id match {
            case 0 => Yes
            case 1 => No
            case _ => Other(msg) ???
        }
    }
}
```

Usage is as it follows:

```
> Answer(0)
Yes
> Answer(1)
No
> Answer(2, "hey")
hey
> Answer(2, "hello")
hello
```

Is it possible? Or should I rather implement some hierarchy of case classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `Other` as a function that takes a `String` and returns a `Value` :

```
object Answer extends Enumeration {
  type Answer = Value

  val Yes = Value("yes")
  val No = Value("no")
  val Other = (s:String) => Value(s)

  def apply(id: Int, msg: String = null) = {
    id match {
      case 0 => Yes
      case 1 => No
      case _ => Other(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as :

```
scala> Answer(0)
res0: Answer.Value = yes

scala> Answer(2, "hello")
res1: Answer.Value = hello

scala> Answer(2, "World")
res2: Answer.Value = World
```